# How to avoid having both circles and pins displayed when zooming in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

[Here's our map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeHuh.jpg)

We're working on a map, trying to have different renderings depending on the zoom level.

- at low zoom level, display circles
- at high zoom level, display map pins with SVG logos inside

Is there any way to have them displayed at the same time at the edge zoom level?

Thanks so much for your help :)

Nothing particular to add there :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Short answer: yes, it's possible, and straightforward to do so. Provide code showing where you got stuck, if you'd like assistance.